# Single Code Base for Web and Mobile Development?

Tags: web-applications, mobile, cordova, ria

I'm planning on setting up a new website and that website will also need a mobile application.

It would be better if I can write one code base for both the web and the mobile without having to re-write for the web and for each mobile platform.

I want to know if there are framework or libraries, something similar to PhoneGap, that can be used to develop for web and mobile with a single code base?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.the-m-project.org/ is a framework that is built for writing web and mobile. Optionally it can be used with PhoneGap as well.